# Exercise 9, Section 3.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on the finite-dimensional space $V$. Suppose there is a linear operator $U$ on $V$ such that $T\circ U=\text{id}_V$. Prove that $T$ is invertible and $U=T^{-1}$.

**My attempt:** Suppose $U\in L(V,V)$ such that $T\circ U=\text{id}_V$. Since $U$ is right inverse of $T$, we have $T$ is surjective ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3571600/861687) is proof). $V$ is finite-dimensional vector space over field $F$. By [theorem 9 section 3.2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4489586/861687), $T$ is bijective. Thus $\exists !$ $T^{-1}:V\to V$ such that $T\circ T^{-1}$ $=\text{id}_V$ $=T^{-1}\circ T$. Since $T\circ U=\text{id}_V$, we have $T^{-1}\circ (T\circ U)$ $=T^{-1}\circ \text{id}_V$ $=T^{-1}$. It’s easy to check composition is associative. So $T^{-1}\circ (T\circ U)$ $=(T^{-1}\circ T)\circ U$ $=\text{id}_V \circ U$ $=U$ $=T^{-1}$. Hence $U=T^{-1}$. **Is my proof correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in\ker U$ then $(T\circ U) x=\text{Id}_V(x) $

Implies $T(U(x)) =x$

Hence $T0=x$ implies $x=0$

Hence $\ker U=\{0\}$ implies $U$ is injective linear operator and then by Rank nullity theorem $U$ is invertible.

Then $T\circ U=\text{Id}_V$ . Hence $(T\circ U)\circ U^{-1}=\text{Id}_V\circ U^{-1}$

implies $T=U^{-1}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think we need to justify $U$ is invertible implies $T$ is invertible.

Comment: We didn’t show $U\circ T=\text{id}_V$, did we?

Comment: Just compose $U^{-1}$  from right side and use associativity of linear map and the fact that $U$ is invertible

Comment: Yesss…. Now it make sense. Since $U$ is bijective and $T=U^{-1}$, we have $T$ is bijective and $U=T^{-1}$.

Comment: $({U}^{-1}) ^{-1}=U$

Comment: Yes. Another way to say “Since $U$ is bijective and $T=U^{-1}$, we have $T$ is bijective and $U=T^{-1}$” is inverse of a bijective map is bijective.

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: ''... by Rank nullity theorem U is invertible.'' This requires a bit more elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

''Let T be a linear operator on the finite-dimensional space V. Suppose there is a linear operator U on V such that T∘U=idV. Prove that T is invertible and U=T−1.''

If $T\circ U = id_V$, then $U$ is injective. This holds more generally for arbitrary functions.
But an injective linear mapping $U:V\rightarrow V$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ is also surjective (this also holds for arbitrary functions when $V$ is a finite set) and so is also surjective. Done.