# Integral of inverse function equality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

I have a theorem in my notes that states:

Let $f$ be an injective and differentiable function in an open interval $I$. We can show that $J=g(I)$ is an open interval, and that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable in $J$. Show that $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(y)dy=bf(b)-af(a).$$

---

Now, reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions) version of the theorem I noticed it used as hypothesis that $f$ is continuous and invertible. What I don't know is if the injectivity of $f$ is enough to prove the theorem. Isn't it true that a function is bijective if and only if it has an inverse? How is injectivity and differentiablity useful here?

Also, I was able to algebraically prove the equality above.

Comment: Injectivity is not enough to guarantee differentiability for the inverse. Consider for example the map $x\mapsto x^3$ in $[-1,1]$. This map is injective and differentiable, but its inverse $x\mapsto x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: @NicolasAgote so the hypothesis in my version of the theorem are wrong?

Comment: What is wrong is that you cannot prove that $f^{-1}$ will be differentiable just from differentiability from $f$. Maybe there were some other hypothesis that do guarantee the result (for example, because of the inverse function theorem if $f'\neq 0$ on your interval $f^{-1}$ will be differentiable everywhere).

Here's a link to the theorem on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

The result is still valid, and can be proved under different hypothesis. I provide a more detailed answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, yes, a function is bijective if and only if it has an inverse. You can find a detailed proof in Herno's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3571600/f-a-to-b-is-invertible-if-and-only-if-bijective). Then injectivity for $f$ is necessary for the result to hold as $f$ needs to be invertible, then bijective, so in particular injective.

If you look at the proof without words in [the Wikipedia page you linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions), it becomes apparent that if $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are integrable functions then the result should hold (look in particular at [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/FunktionUmkehrIntegral2.svg/220px-FunktionUmkehrIntegral2.svg.png)). In this case, continuity for $f$ and $f^{-1}$ suffices to guarantee (Riemann) integrability, so it *can* be proved without using the stronger hypothesis of differentiability and replacing it by continuity for $f$ (with the necessary injectivity). Of course, differentiability allows the use of stronger theorems and results than just continuity, so some different proofs may be enabled once one assumes the functions $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are differentiable (as is mentioned in the article, differentiating will prove the result immediately).